# Java 8: Merge List<List<List<Product>> into one list

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have 3 lists, `List<List<List<Product>>` that I want to flatten into one. I've read several SO articles, but I'm still not sure how to proceed. So far I have

```
allProducts.stream()
    .flatMap(List::Stream)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But that only merges two of the lists, right? What's the best way to merge all three in that statement? I've seen `reduce()` used, but I'm not sure how to write that. I need to get to a single list of `Product`.

Comment: Seriously, if you have that kind of data structure then I think you need to introduce some intermediate classes. What kind of thing is a three deep list supposed to represent? Next question, how to flatmap 4 lists List<List<List<List<T>>>>?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to chain 2 `flatMap`s:

```
allProducts.stream() // Stream<List<List<Product>>>
           .flatMap(List::stream) // Stream<List<Product>>
           .flatMap(List::stream) // Stream<Product>
           .collect(Collectors.toList()); // List<Product>
```